# Can i carry power through ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet

I am thinking of using CAT6 cable to send video and power to CCTV cameras. I know that CAT6 cable can carry the video signal, but I want to know if I can also pass the power to cameras via one pair of wires of the Ethernet cable.

Comment: Technically, you can send power over any cable. The receiving end just needs to support it.

Comment: By tagging, `power-over-ethernet`, you seem to have answered your own question however.

Comment: Like what Nate and Cole have said, in theory, you can use whatever cable you want, it just depends on the pinout of the devices.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as long as your device supports PoE (Power over Ethernet).

You'll also need a switch that supports PoE or you'll need to add PoE to the line with an adapter.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand fully. What is diff between PoE and normal power. I just want to use it as medium. I mean one end i want to coonect the one pair of ethernet 8 wires to CCTV camera and other end to power suppy adapter. Can i just join them with tape

Comment: @user1315279, PoE is the standard way of doing what you're asking about. Trying to use an ethernet cable to carry a voltage or current higher could be dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is what I think it is, you are asking about connecting power inputs of a CCTV camera to the wires in a CAT6 cable like so:

```
 | ]--- V+
 | ]--- V+  *To CCTV cameras*
 | ]--- V+                                 *To power supply*
 | ]--- V- / GND                           V-/GND V+
 | |                                           |  |
 | |  *CAT6 cable*                             |  .__....
 | |___________________________________________|__|__||||
 \_______________________________________________________|
```

If so, then yes, you can do that. Just make sure that you are not drawing too much power through the cables

Answer (score 1):

The PoE standard requires electricity be DC, 22v or less, 18W or less.  In practice several companies make perfectly functional products that violate the standard.  You'll have to experiment to make sure yours doesn't corrupt the data stream.  Just remember to use pins 7 & 8.

Comment: Is this per wire or for all 8?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a need to split a Ethernet cable on any pin-out. The POE standard allows for power to be carried over a standard Ethernet cable (CAT5e and above)
As long as your switch and terminating device (camera, access point, etc.) are rated for POE.
I would never recommend or advocate modifying a cable - you're asking for trouble when you start to modify things.

Answer (score 0):

Hey am an Electronics Engeneer if you crimp one end with a straight through standard you will have current on the following two wires Blue and Orange White...however only try this as an experiment with the crimped end connected to a Poe adapter

Comment: Use this This standard though GGWBBWBBWOOW

Comment: Can you explain that standard in more detail?